# Laravel Update Query

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to update a User on the basis of the email not there id, is there a way of doing this without raw queries.

**Currently the error**

> {"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Creating default object
>   from empty
>   value","file":"C:\wamp\www\celeb-jim\app\controllers\SignupController.php","line":189}}

**My Code**

> ```
>     public function changeAccountStatus ($plan, $userEmail ){
>         $UpdateDetails = User::where('email', '=',  $userEmail)->first();
>         $UpdateDetails->member_type = $plan;
>         $UpdateDetails->save();
>     }
> ```

Comment: And what's in line `189`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This error would suggest that `User::where('email', '=', $userEmail)->first()` is returning null, rather than a problem with updating your model.

Check that you actually have a User before attempting to change properties on it, or use the `firstOrFail()` method.

```
$UpdateDetails = User::where('email', $userEmail)->first();

if (is_null($UpdateDetails)) {
    return false;
}
```

or using the `firstOrFail()` method, theres no need to check if the user is null because this throws an exception (`ModelNotFoundException`) when a model is not found, which you can catch using `App::error()` http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#handling-errors

```
$UpdateDetails = User::where('email', $userEmail)->firstOrFail();
```

Answer (score 39):

You could use the [Laravel query builder](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#updates), but **this is not the best way to do it**.

Check [Wader's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27248975/658210) for the Eloquent way - which is better as it allows you to check that there is actually a user that matches the email address, and handle the error if there isn't.

```
DB::table('users')
        ->where('email', $userEmail)  // find your user by their email
        ->limit(1)  // optional - to ensure only one record is updated.
        ->update(array('member_type' => $plan));  // update the record in the DB.
```

If you have multiple fields to update you can simply add more values to that array at the end.

Comment: I guess you did not understand the question. He wants to supply email in Eloquent find() method and wants it to match against emil column

Comment: Why would you use the Query Builder for this when op has an Eloquent model setup? The problem is not that this cannot be done easily in Eloquent, but the fact there is no null checking before attempting to set properties on the object (See my answer)

Comment: @Wader yes, you're right. I'd delete this if it wasn't accepted.  That +1 on yours is from me.  I'll update this to make it clearer

Comment: I wasn't saying this was wrong, simply questioning the benefits to using the Query Builder over Eloquent. I realise my comment sounds quite harsh, apologies

Comment: @Wader no problem, you were right to question it.. Yours is the better answer!

Answer (score 23):

Try doing it like this.

```
User::where('email', $userEmail)
       ->update([
           'member_type' => $plan
        ]);
```

Comment: User::where('email', $userEmail)->update(['member_type' => $plan]);

Comment: That's the best solution, cause this code executing only one sql query instead of others

Answer (score 9):

```
$update = \DB::table('student') ->where('id', $data['id']) ->limit(1) ->update( [ 'name' => $data['name'], 'address' => $data['address'], 'email' => $data['email'], 'contactno' => $data['contactno'] ]);
```

Answer (score 7):

> It is very simple to do. Code are given below :

```
 DB::table('user')->where('email', $userEmail)->update(array('member_type' => $plan));
```